# Enumerated types and their interpretation by compilers

Tags: compiler, interpreters, enum

It seems to me that a lot, if not most, compilers treat enumerated types as `int` underneath. In C/gcc, `enum`s are compiled to `int`. In C#/Visual C#, you can change the underlying data type with something like:

```
enum Days : byte {Sat=1, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};
```

but [the default is `int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc138362%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (second paragraph) if you don't change the type.

For obvious reasons, `int`s are efficient. They fly through the ALU with ease and avoid useless string comparisons.

Upon first glance, it doesn't seem that interpreted languages have enumerated types built-in (Ruby, Perl, JavaScript, others I'm sure). They can be emulated though; i.e. [in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/287903/1986871).

My questions:

1. Why do (seemingly) most compilers use `int` as the underlying type? Is the reason historical/performance-related?
2. Are there languages that compile enumerated types to something other than `int` (or `byte`, `long`, *numerical types*...)? If so, why did they choose to do it differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of your question will be difficult to answer because that decision was made long ago and one would need to ask the creators of languages such as C to know for sure.

Your second point is quite answerable.

- Java created the `enum` type in response to the widespread use of `int` constants which do not behave well ([Effective Java, Second Edition, Bloch](http://smile.amazon.com/Effective-Java-2nd-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683/), Item 30/Page 147). For example, you can multiply two integer constants in a nonsensical manner but you cannot do the same with two `enum` values. It is possible to multiple `RED` with `BLUE` when using integer constants, but not enums. What does that mean, anyway?

  In addition, this decision was made because the enumeration type can be "smarter." It can contain values as well as encapsulate behavior inside each enum value. Rather than having a `switch` over the enum values which is brittle and a maintenance problem, invert the logic and put the body of each `case` inside each individual enum. Now call a method on your enum variable, and use [dynamic dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) to abstract your switch. Now the enum has its values and behavior localized to the same class.
- C++ 11 now includes the `enum class` construct which was done because languages such as Java implemented "intelligent" enums with good success. ([The C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition, Stroustrup](http://smile.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-4th/dp/0321563840/), Section 8.4/Page 218).

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to shed some light based on languages I'm most familiar with:

**D**:

[Enumerators in the D language](http://dlang.org/enum.html) are just another way of declaring compile-time constants. They are are very flexible and allow enums of string type, which is not very usual. Control of the size of integer constants is also possible. See the bottom of the page in the previous link for several examples.

**C++**:

Old-style unscoped enums in C++ are not required to have the size of a C++ `int` object. They can be larger than that. Quoting [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum):

> an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is not fixed ... in
>   this case, the underlying type is either `int` or, if not all
>   enumerator values can be represented as `int`, an
>   implementation-defined larger integral type that can represent all
>   enumerator values.

So if we compare the size of these two C++ enumerators:

```
enum Test1 {
    A1,
    B1
};
enum Test2 {
    A2,
    B2 = 18446744073709551615ULL /* UINT64_MAX */
};
```

The first one will be the size of a default integer (`int`) and the second, the size of a 64bit integer (`long long int`) to fit the large constant.

The new `enum class` introduced in C++11 allows the user to specify the size of the enum type and its constants. The constants are also scoped. They are very similar to a C# enumerator.

**Why are integers the common case?**

I'll speculate that integers are commonly the default choice for enumerator types in programming languages because of simplicity. The machine can only really deal with numbers. Even a text string is just and array of numbers interpreted in a special way by the program.